# How to create dotNet 6 self installing service?

Tags: .net, f#

This used to be relatively easy using System.Configuration.Install module, which is unavailable since .Net 5 and isn't in 6.0 either.

The point is not using WinAPI and nothing besides standard .Net classes too.

Target implementation language is F#.

Comment: Use PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService from NuGet.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for Windows? Try the free PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService from NuGet. Works in .NET Core 3, .NET 5, and I believe also in .NET 6. For similar free functionality for .NET Framework, have a look at TopShelf.

The assumption is that in DEBUG you're running as a command line application in VS, and when not in DEBUG you're running as an actual service in Windows. When in DEBUG, the Ctrl-C handler is installed, and Ctrl-C is then used to stop properly by running the service's stop handler. If the command shell window is just closed as a window, then the stop handler won't get a chance to run.

There is a call to a WinAPI function in this source, but only when in DEBUG, for the Ctrl-C handler. As for the library, I don't know what API it uses.

```
namespace ThisIsMyServiceApp

open System
open System.Text
open PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService
open PeterKottas.DotNetCore.WindowsService.Interfaces

module Program =

    let log = MyLogging.MainLog

    let mutable private oneShot = false

    let runOneShot () =
        if not oneShot then
            // TODO: Do stuff here that should only run once on app start, whether as service or app debug in VS.
            oneShot <- true
            if not Runtime.GCSettings.IsServerGC then
                log.Warning "Workstation garbage collection in effect."
            Encoding.RegisterProvider CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance // Support for ANSI codepage 1252

    let mutable private service: IMicroService = null

    type MyService(controller: IMicroServiceController) =

        new () = MyService(null)

        interface IMicroService with

            member x.Start() =
                runOneShot ()
                // TODO: Do stuff here on start.
                service <- x
                ()

            member _.Stop() =
                // TODO: Do stuff here on stop.
                ()

#if DEBUG
    let ConsoleEventCallback (eventType: int) : bool =
        if eventType = 2 then
            log.Info "Console window closing, death imminent."
            if service <> null then
                service.Stop () |> ignore
        else
            log.Info "Some other ConsoleCtrlHandler event occured."
        false

    type ConsoleEventDelegate = delegate of int -> bool

    let mutable consoleExitHandler: ConsoleEventDelegate = null

    module private Imported =

        open System.Runtime.InteropServices

        [<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)>]
        extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleEventDelegate callback, bool add)
#endif

    // Commands for installation etc :
    // https://github.com/PeterKottas/DotNetCore.WindowsService

    let [<EntryPoint>] main argv =
        runOneShot ()
#if DEBUG
        consoleExitHandler <- new ConsoleEventDelegate(ConsoleEventCallback)
        Imported.SetConsoleCtrlHandler (consoleExitHandler, true) |> ignore
#endif
        let exitCode = ServiceRunner<MyService>.Run(fun config ->
            config.SetName "MyService"
            config.SetDisplayName "MyService"
            config.SetDescription "This is MyService"
            config.SetServiceTimeout 60_000
            let name = config.GetDefaultName()

            let serviceFactory = (fun (extraArguments: ResizeArray<string>) (controller: IMicroServiceController) ->
                new MyService(controller)
                )

            let onStart (service: MyService) (extraParams: ResizeArray<string>) =
                log.Verbose $"Service {name} starting."
                let iservice = service :> IMicroService
                iservice.Start()
                log.Verbose $"Service {name} started."
                ()

            let onStop (service: MyService) =
                log.Verbose $"Service {name} stopping."
                let iservice = service :> IMicroService
                iservice.Stop()
                log.Verbose $"Service {name} stopped."
                ()

            let shutdown (service: MyService) =
                log.Verbose $"Service {name} shutdown."
                ()

            let onError (ex: exn) =
                log.Exn ex $"Service {name} errored with exception : {ex.Message}"
                ()

            config.Service(fun serviceConfig ->
                serviceConfig.ServiceFactory(Func<_,_,_>serviceFactory)
                serviceConfig.OnStart(Action<_,_>onStart)
                serviceConfig.OnStop(Action<_>onStop)
                serviceConfig.OnShutdown(Action<_>shutdown)
                serviceConfig.OnError(Action<_>onError)
            )
        )
        match exitCode with
        | 0 -> log.Info "MyService exited normally."
        | exitCode ->
            log.Warning $"MyService exited with code {exitCode}."
            if exitCode = 7 then
                log.Warning "NOTE! Service and console application must not run at the same time."

        // Only use this to save the situation when the app is hung e.g. due to not releasing resources.
        Environment.Exit exitCode // Because it hangs otherwise.

        exitCode
```